Set-WUSettings : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'WUStatusServer'
Windows Server 2022 Standard
10.0.20348 N/A Build 20348
I can set other parameters (i.e -WUServer), but I cannot seem to set the "-WUStatusServer". I get an error, that this parameter does not exist.
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll -IgnoreUserInput -IgnoreReboot -Download -Verbose
VERBOSE: EE02-MGMT-AD1 (4/15/2024 8:44:20 AM): Connecting to Windows Update server. Please wait...
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-WUSettings -WUServer "http://blabla.domain.com:8530" -WUStatusServer "http:///blabla.domain.com:8530" -UseWUServer -Verbose -Confirm:$false

However, when I manually create "WUStatusServer" under "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
Then it will show it also:
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-wusettings
ComputerName   : servername1
WUServer       : http://blabla.domain.com:8530
WUStatusServer : http://blabla.domain.com:8530
AUOptions      : 3 - Notify before installation
UseWUServer    : 1

Can anyone tell me, why the "Set-WUSettings" does not work.
Regards
Raul
I have specified all the command already.
